# Read csv of ints into single list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a csv of integers and I want to read them all into one list in Python. How exactly can I do that?

I have searched a bunch on here and every piece of code I tried would output a row of integers as a list and thus creates a list of lists.

Ideally I am looking for something like this as an output: `[2,4,6,6,4,6,4,12,12,4]` but I keep getting this: `[[2,4,6,6,4,'',],[6,4,12,12,4,'',],...]`

Here is a snippet of the csv:
[image]

Comment: please show your code

Comment: and the csv file

Comment: Post some of the code you have already tried and we will help you get it working better. A snippet of the csv file would also be helpful!

Comment: I added a snippet of the csv. I made a bad choice and did not keep the file in which I had tested previous implementations. I will make sure to include past code in future posts. I apologize!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
import csv

path = 'text.csv'                #change to path of your csv file
thelist = []                     #define new list

with open(path, 'r') as csvfile: #open csv file
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile) #read it
    for row in reader:           #iterate through each row 
        for item in row:         #iterate through each item of that row
            thelist.append(int(item)) #convert item to an int and add it to thelist


print(thelist)                   #print it
```

Note that all the items in the csv file must be integers for this to work, or it will throw an error. You can change `int(item)` to `item` to just get a list of strings

text.csv:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
7,8,9,0,1,2
3,4,5,6,7,8
4,5,6,7,8,9
```

OUTPUT:

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

**Bonus, probably useless, one-liners (without the `csv` module):**

With list comprehension:

```py
thelist = [int(item) for item in open('text.csv').read().replace('\n', ',').split(',')]
```

...or, with `map`:

```py
thelist = list(map(int, open('text.csv').read().replace('\n', ',').split(',')))
```

...or with `with`, which automatically closes the file after using it:

```
with open('text.csv') as f: thelist = list(map(int, f.read().replace('\n',',').split(',')))
```

[Run and edit these one-liners online](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/MistyAptArraylist#main.py)

Comment: how do you close the file as you will end up getting resource warning trace malloc if you use the oneliner?

Comment: @NandeepDevendra - I've edited my answer to include a one-liner that opens the file using `with open(...` rather than just `open`, which should close the file when it's finished reading. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: great, it works now thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `list.extend()` to add cell items to the list:

[image]

```
import csv 

with open('data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    mylist = []
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
        mylist.extend(map(int,row))

>>> print(mylist)
[2, 4, 6, 6, 4, 6, 4, 12, 12, 4]
```

Comment: This solution worked too! Just wanted to give proper credit.